# Single "find" command with multiple arguments?

Tags: unix, permissions, find

I need to devise a single `find` command that searches for:

- All C# or Java programs
- Located in the home directory of the current user
- Have at least one hard link
- Readable for everybody
- Have at least one write bit set
- Not executable for anybody

I have come up with answers for everything except the last criterion and here's my code:

```
find /home -name "*.c" "*.java" -links 1 (-perm -a=r -a -perm -a=!x)
```

I don't really think it's right and it is incomplete. Help?

Answer (score 1):

```
find $HOME \(-name '*.java -o -name '*.c' \) \    # home directory && filenames
      -link +0                               \    # one or more hard links
      ! -perm -111                           \    # not executable by anybody  -111 means "any of" 
       -perm /444                            \    # at least one write bit set
       -perm 666                                 # ugo read
```

You can smash this back together into one longer, harder to read line.  I broke it out to make it readable.